# Count(1) and the Like statement Best use/Performance

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Is there a better way of doing the below sql query I am not sure if the Like statement is the best option as the location column only contains exact matches.

```
INSERT INTO test_reports (Table_Name, Total_Count)
SELECT "table1", COUNT(1)
  FROM table1
 WHERE location LIKE 'birmingham'
```

Comment: Well, if you don't have any wildcards in your `like` clause, you might as well just use an `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no wildcards in your search string.  Without wildcards, `like` is exactly the same as `=`.

Comment: Thought so i will use = thats what i forgot. Thanks